# flutter_map: Best way to embed whole world map (just landmass, no details)?

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I'm developing an aviation app in Flutter, currently using flutter_map which seems to be a great tool and easily allows to display custom Markers.
I need to preload the whole world map in the app, but really no details, pretty much like on the picture below. Landmasses and country borders ideally, that's it.

I tried flutter_map_tile_caching, great plugin indeed, but downloading tiles from openstreetmap as I do now for limited areas, it would be a totally unrealistic amount of data, even limiting at a very low zoom level... And I don't need those details.

I'm new in the "mapping business", so any hint about how to achieve this would be most welcome. I'm open to using other libraries if need be.

Best regards!

[image]

Comment: check [TileOverlay](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/TileOverlay-class.html), they say: *"A set of images which are displayed on top of the base map tiles.

These tiles may be transparent, allowing you to add features to existing maps."* - in your case "these tiles" can be opaque so they will be the only thing your app will show

Comment: I'm not familiar with the google maps library for Flutter. I've googled TileOverlay a bit, but I'm still failing to grasp how it can help me to have a simple land and countries maps, lightweight enough to be downloaded and embedded in the app?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not much input here.
I found a decent solution for now, caching maps from openstreetmaps at zoom 7 for the most relevant region, and then at zoom 4 for the wider region, displaying the best zoom one on top with a transparent default tile, so that the lower resolution one will show around. That keeps the downloaded files to a decent size.
For the whole globe, there's a possibility to use shapes files I believe. (like https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/land-polygons.html or such), but didn't make it work with flutter_map yet. I'll investigate in a further iteration.
Cheers!

Comment: Hey, if you ever need help with my caching library, please get in touch. Always happy to help :)

Comment: Thank you so much... Your library is working wonders for my app indeed :) As I wrote in the post above, I managed to find a solution which is working well, but will be a little too geographically limited in the longer run, as the app can get users from different parts of the world. If you have any idea how I could achieve that, to be able to cache the whole world outlines, without needing to store hundreds of MB, that would be awesome. I'll keep on digging on my side. Thanks again for both the great library and for the support :)

Comment: You should be able to download just between zoom levels 1 & 3/4, which should give the whole outline in probably less than a MB

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but it got very blurry when zooming in on an area... that's why I wondered if shapes could be a solution. But I'm not sure an easy solution is at hand here. It's quite a special requirement I have. I'll tell you if I find a good solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I use https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ to generate a json file which I then link to my app via `pubspec.yaml`. For example this json removes quite a lot of info from maps:

```
[
    {
      "elementType": "labels",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "off"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "labels",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "visibility": "on"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Add it to `pubspec.yaml` like:

```
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/empty_map_style.json
```

You should then do something like this to load the styles:

```
  void _setMapStyles() async {
      final _style =
          await MapUtils.getStyles("assets/empty_map_style.json");

      (await _mapCtrl.future).setMapStyle(_style);
  }
```

I would call this method inside `onMapCreated` of `GoogleMap` widget

Comment: Thank you Eric! Sorry for coming back to it so late, having a "working solution" for now, I had to prioritize other aspects of the project. But this solution is geographically limited, so I'm still looking for a way to cache the whole world basic outlines.

I tried this, and it definitely remove lots of details from the maps, but is it possible to cache the maps from Google Maps for offline use?